# What is a database in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, database

I was wondering in general, what exactly is a database and is there a difference between that and a geodatabase? I was also wondering when you would use a database as part of ArcGIS. Do you make one each time you have a new file?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that, after researching it first, there should be only one focussed question asked in each question here.  In this case it does not seem like you have used a search engine to search on "ArcGIS database geodatabase" before asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is an intro to geodatabases

http://www.acct2day.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Geodatabase-an-Introduction.pdf

http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00050000000r000000

and to answer the final question, no you do not make a new one each time you make a new file (if i understand your question correctly)